# Access permissions for @everyone in a channel Discord.js v14

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I would like to check if `@everyone` has an specific permission on a defined channel.

In v13, I had it working just fine:

```
const channelPermissions = channel.guild.roles.everyone.permissionsIn(channel);

if (channelPermissions.has([Permissions.FLAGS.SEND_MESSAGES, Permissions.FLAGS.VIEW_CHANNEL])) {
   interaction.reply('Hey! You can use this channel!');
}
```

In v14, the [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/Role?scrollTo=permissionsIn) and the [official guide](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v14.html#permissionoverwritesmanager) do not hint a breaking change on this method.

This is my attempt at making it work:

```
const { PermissionsBitField } = require('discord.js');

const channelPermissions = interaction.channel.guild.roles.everyone.permissionsIn(channel);

if (channelPermissions.has([PermissionsBitField.Flags.SendMessages, PermissionsBitField.Flags.ViewChannel])) {
   interaction.reply('Hey! You can use this channel!');
}
```

However, everytime it executes I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'has')
```

As the [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/PermissionsBitField?scrollTo=has) say as well, the `has()` modal is the same as before, and I do not understand where this error is coming from.

Any help or explanation will be welcome. Thank you!

Comment: It's strange, I can't reproduce the error. If `channel` is a valid snowflake or a valid channel, there is no error with your code. And I've only added the `GatewayIntentBits.Guilds` intent.

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros my `channel` is valid, and my bot has `32767` as intents, do you wish that I share my full code so you can take a look if you want? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly me! More above in the code, a typo in a `if/else` statement would make `channelPermissions` null.

However, while asking for help in the [Discord.js support server](https://discord.com/invite/djs), someone shared with me another way to get permissions from `@everyone` on a channel:

```
const channelPermissions = channel.permissionsFor(interaction.guild.id);
```

Guess I should be more careful next time!